# Numberpicker send data to HomeFragment (Fragment to Fragment)

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, numberpicker

I have app who have viewpagers and in inside is numberpicker. I try to send this data to my HomeFragment but crash my app. This is my source code. What i do wrong?

**Create Interface for communication**

```
interface Communicator {
fun passData(numberpicker: NumberPicker) {

}
```

**This is my fragment with numberpicker**

lateinit var comm: Communicator

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
 val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_period_length, container, false)

  view.number_picker_period?.minValue = 21
    view.number_picker_period?.maxValue = 35
    view.number_picker_period?.wrapSelectorWheel = true

    val viewPager = activity?.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager)

    view.next_txt_period.setOnClickListener {
        viewPager?.currentItem = 1
        comm.passData(view.number_picker_period)


    }






 return view
}
```

**This is MainActivity**

```
  val fragment1 = DaysLength()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_id, fragment1).commit()



}

override fun passData(numberpicker: NumberPicker) {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("input_txt", number_picker_period.toString())

    val transaction = this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val fragment2 = HomeFragment()
    fragment2.arguments = bundle
}
```

**My HomeFragment**

```
  var inputtext: String? = ""

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

    inputtext = arguments?.getString("input_txt")

    view.output_numberpicker.text = inputtext

    return view
```

What i do wrong?

**Error**

```
 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oapp/com.example.oapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080067 (com.example.oapp:id/content_id) for fragment DaysLength{aa77410}
```

Comment: Could you please put more details in MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

your main activity is crashing on this line as it doesn't know what the view "number_picker_period" is

```
  bundle.putString("input_txt", number_picker_period.toString())
```

try accessing the number picker through the parameter in the function called "numberPicker", Or alternatively, change your passData interface function to return the string value instead of the entire numberPicker